# Using two separate loops for one variable - python

Tags: python

I'm working on a program for school and I'm supposed to grab user input and use it in two separate loops.

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number! "))


print("Output from for loop:")
for i in range (n, 101):
  print(n)
  n += 1

print("Output with while loop:")
while n <= 100:
  print(n)
  n += 1
```

After the first loop runs, I assume the variable changes to 100 and the second loop doesn't run, how should I go about solving this issue? It's clear from the prompt to use only one input.

class example:

```
Please input an integer value to start counting to 100: 92
Output from For loop:
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
Output from While loop:
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're changing the value of `n` in the first loop, and so by the time you get to the second loop, it is already > 100.  And so the second loop doesn't do anything.  Here's a simple way to fix it:

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number! "))

print("Output from for loop:")
for i in range (n, 101):
  print(i)

print("Output with while loop:")
while n <= 100:
  print(n)
  n += 1
```

Result:

```
Please enter a number! 92
Output from for loop:
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
Output with while loop:
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

In the first loop, `i` is already the value you want to print.  No need to increment 'n' and mess it up.  If you had really needed to increment a value like `n` separate from `i`, you could copy `n` to say `nn` and then increment and print that.  But in this case, why not just use `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set another variable (n2) as n. then you can use at the while loop
like this:

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number! "))
n2 = n

print("Output from for loop:")
for i in range (n, 101):
  print(n)
  n += 1

print("Output with while loop:")
while n2 <= 100:
  print(n2)
  n2 += 1
```

output:

```
Please enter a number! 92
Output from for loop:
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
Output with while loop:
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number! "))

print("Output from for loop:")
for i in range (n, 101):
  print(i)


print("Output with while loop:")
while n <= 100:
  print(n)
  n += 1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it